# How to use wildcard search in FIND_IN_SET() mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, wildcard, find-in-set

I have a stored procedure I want to use Wildcard search in FIND_IN_SET

```
AND IF(ipc IS NOT NULL,FIND_IN_SET(b.ipc_class_symbol, ipc),1=1));
```

ipc is varchar like "F03D, F02D", etc I want to search in "F03D%, F02D%" which is not giving any results. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **[SUBSTR](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php)** to truncate `F03D%` to `F03D`

```
AND IF(ipc IS NOT NULL,FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTR(b.ipc_class_symbol,1,4), ipc),1=1));
```

Comment: but sometime I also want "F03D1%" hence I want to use wildcard

Comment: @HarshdeepKanhai What I am saying is just to remove `%` for it